# Making a bash script holiday aware

Tags: bash, shell

I was about to embark on writing a bash script (as a bash newbie). The purpose of the script is to be enforce the requirement that some other commands (i.e. the work part of the script) dosen't run on holidays.

I found the snippet below [online](http://www.genlinux.org/2011/02/shell-script-to-rub-particular-on-job.html):

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -i date holiday.txt
if[ $? -ne 0] then;
#script to run the jobs
exit
fi
```

Although I admit I am a bash neophyte, I can't seem to spot anything wrong with this script - yet at the same time, it looks a little too "simplistic" - are there any "gotchas" that my untrained eye cannot spot now, but will come to bite me in the rear later on?

I am running GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release

Comment: Not all holidays are on the same date each year, e.g. Easter, Labor Day. You'd have to regenerate your holiday.txt each year to account for such things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

example of holiday.txt

```
2011-11-25 // testing purpose
2011-12-25
2012-01-01
```

```
if test $(grep $(date +%Y-%m-%d) holiday.txt -ic) -ne 0
then
   # your action list
fi
```

Comment: thanks for the sample dataset as well,  I was wondering about the date format ...

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me, except for syntax  and except for I'm not sure you want the output on the screen. You may prefer

```
if ! grep -q -i date holiday.txt ; then
    true
    exit
fi
```

In original code I think you need to swap `;` and `then` and add space before `[`.

Also, if the code is short

```
grep -q -i date holiday.txt || somethingbeingdone
```

maybe more convenient way to do it.